# Php 5.6 and Mysql 5.6.x on Debian 8.10

Tags: debian, mysql, php

Is it possible to run Php 5.6 and Mysql 5.6.x on Debian 8.10?

Comment: as far as I remember they were the default in 8...now for Debian 9 that is another talk.

Comment: 9 uses maria and php7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-5.6 is available on debian jessie , it can be installed through:

```
apt-get install php5
```

MySQL-5.6 can be installed through [MySQL APT repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/):

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
```

Choose Debian jessie then update and install the `5.6` version of `mysql` through the `mysql-community-server` package :

```
apt-get install mysql-community-server
mysql_secure_installation
mysql_install_db
systemctl start mysql
```

Check MySQL version:

```
mysqladmin -p -u root version
```

sample output:

```
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.6.39, for Linux on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Server version      5.6.39
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         1 min 32 sec
```

or `mysql --version`:

```
 mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.39, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6 in Debian 8 and indeed they are the default for Debian 8.

Just do for installing them, as the very basic:

```
apt-get install mysql-server php5
```

I d however recommend for a better experience:

```
apt-get install mysql-server php5 php-pear php5-mysql apache2
```

Comment: Debian 8 doesn’t have MySQL 5.6 though, the latest version there is 5.5.58 (soon to be replaced by 5.5.59). I doubt there’s any practical difference though...

Comment: True indeed, the real difference is from 5.6 to 5.7